# How to catch the remainder of a regex .match()?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible, in JavaScript, to catch the remainder of a regex `.match()`?

For example:

```
var string = "505 Swanton St";

var m = string.match(/\d+/);
```

I can access "505" with `m[0]`, but there are no other elements in `m's` array.

Is there a way to catch the remainder of `string`?

Comment: If you just want to store it in a variable, you can use replace and catch everything after what's matched with the string parameter $`` (one backtick: I can't get SO to show only one), eg: var string = "505 Swanton St"; var after = string.replace(/\d+/g, "$`"); console.log(after);//Swanton St

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can catch everything before and after the pattern using [capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references):

```
var string = "505 Swanton St";

var m = string.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)(.*)$/);
```

Here:

```
m[0] == "505 Swanton St";  // the entire matched pattern
m[1] == "";                // first group
m[2] == "505";             // second group
m[3] == " Swanton St";     // third group
```

```js
var string = "505 Swanton St";

var m = string.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)(.*)$/);

console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
```

Answer (score 3):

`string.match` and `regexp.exec` return special arrays with the added `index` property which is the index of the first character of the match. So you could also get the remainder with:

```
var string = "505 Swanton St";
var m = string.match(/\d+/);
var remainder = string.substring(0, m.index) + string.substring(m[0].length);
```

If used with a regex with the /g flag and the `regex.exec` function instead, you'll need to keep concatenating parts the  between the end of a match and the beginning of the next.

```
function parseInput(input) {
  parseInput.regex.lastIndex = 0;
  var matches = [];
  var remainder = "";
  var prevIndex = 0;

  while((match = parseInput.regex.exec(input)) !== null) {
    matches.push(match);
    remainder += input.substring(prevIndex, match.index);
    prevIndex = parseInput.regex.lastIndex;
  }

  if(matches.length) {
    remainder += input.substring(prevIndex); // after last result
    return {"matches": matches, "remainder": remainder};
  } else {
    return {"matches": null, "remainder": input};
  }
}
parseInput.regex = /\d+/g;
```

I used this with a much more complex regex to parse all kinds of units. If there's an extraneous decimal point, my regex won't grab it and it will be in the remainder, so I can tell there's an error in the input by simply looking for points in the remainder.

*** EDIT: Fixed the parseInput function so it also gets the remainder after the last match  ***

Comment: Ooops, I noticed a bug in the function, it didn't return the portion of the string after the last match. "1a2b3c" returned a remainder of "ab". I fixed it.